# I don't want the data registration in Firebase to be numbered Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I do not want numbering to appear, I want the time to appear as written in the code, so what is the reason for such a problem to appear?

```
deviceModels.add(new DeviceModel(newDeviceName, newDeviceWat, newDeviceUse, currentDateAndTime));

FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference();
    databaseReference.child("DeviceInfo").child(currentUser).child(currentDateAndTime).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            // data base reference will sends data to firebase.
            databaseReference.setValue(deviceModels);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "تم أضافة الجهاز", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            dialog.dismiss();
            finish();
            startActivity(getIntent());
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your `deviceModels` is an array or a `List`, and this is how the Firebase Realtime Database persists arrays/lists. There is no way to configure it to do it differently, but you can of course use a different data type in your code.

More idiomatic in Firebase is to use the `push()` method when adding items to a list on the database. To learn more about why that is, have a look at [Best Practices: Arrays in Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html).

In your case you'd write the data for each individual `DeviceModel`:

```
databaseReference.push().setValue(new DeviceModel(newDeviceName, newDeviceWat, newDeviceUse, currentDateAndTime));
```

This will then end up in the database as:

```
DeviceInfo: {
  "IN0r....T2": {
    "-N.....": {
      deviceId: ...,
      deviceName: ...
    }
  }
}
```

And that entire list would then map back to a `Map<String, DeviceModel>` in your Java code.